# How to show rating along with comments?

Tags: rating

could anyone tell me how to display rating along with comments? Am working on an ecommerce site and am using five star module for rating. i have configured the five star module where we can rate when posting comments. But after the comments have been submitted the rating does not show up along with respective comments. How to bring rating along with comments?

Answer (score 0):

- Goto: `admin/structure/types/manage/theme-display/comment/fields`. In Add existing field select **Fivestar Rating** and save

I have added screenshot [image]